# Images falling outside container with max height

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a container that contains 3 images. I want the image on the left to take up 100% of the container height, and the two on the right to take up 50% each and be stacked.

However when I set a max height on my gallery container of 400px, as the images are taller they fall out.

How can I fix this?

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="gallery">
      <div class="main-image">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/710x533" />
      </div>
      <div class="sub-image">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/357x266" /> 
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/357x266" />
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.container {
    max-width: 1100px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 1rem;
}

.gallery {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  max-height:400px;
  border: 5px solid red;
};

.main-image {
  img {
    height: 100%;
  }
  flex: 1 0 66%;
  min-height: 500px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
}



.sub-image {
  flex: 1 0 33%;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: stretch;
  align-items: stretch;
  height: 100%;
};
```

I have the code in codepen

https://codepen.io/roynev123/pen/abWPQyw

Comment: Your CSS is wrong somewhere. You have a closing brace after `img` but no selector for the next rule.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve what you're looking for with the following CSS:

```
.container {
    max-width: 1100px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 1rem;
}

.gallery {
  border: 5px solid red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  max-height: 400px;
}

img {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.main-image {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  width: 66.67%;
}

.sub-image img {
  height: 50%;
}
```

Basically, `.gallery` acts a a flexbox container, with `.main-image` having a static width.